# How to make three texts position on top of each slots respectively?

Tags: sass, pug, text-alignment

I am developing a simple random name picker website and I would like to know how to make three texts positioned on top of each slot and aligned center in each slot simultaneously.

The current image of the website looks like this.[image: Current website]

Pug/ Jade:

```
#lucky-draw
.title
  //- Pug loader currently does not handle webpack alias so we will use relative path here
  include ../assets/images/title.svg

.slots-header-container
  .slot-text-left
    p Left Additional Text

  .slot-text-center
    p Center Additional Text

  .slot-text-right
    p Right Additional Text

.slots-container
  .slot
    .slot__outer
      .slot__inner
        .slot__shadow
          #reel.reel

    #sunburst.sunburst
      img(src="~@images/sunburst.svg" alt="sunburst")

  .slot
    .slot__outer
      .slot__inner
        .slot__shadow
          #reel.reel

    #sunburst.sunburst
      img(src="~@images/sunburst.svg" alt="sunburst")

  .slot
    .slot__outer
      .slot__inner
        .slot__shadow
          #reel.reel

    #sunburst.sunburst
      img(src="~@images/sunburst.svg" alt="sunburst")

button#draw-button.solid-button Run!
```

Sass:

```
.slots-header-container{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%; // Adjust as needed to move them further upward
  width: 100%;
}

.slot-text-left {
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 10px; // Adjust as needed
}

.slot-text-right {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 10px; // Adjust as needed
}
```

Comment: Consider providing more code to replicate your screenshot. Currently, your code [renders like this in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1uLv968f/) which does not look like your screenshot.

Comment: Also, this is a question about HTML and CSS, not about Pug or Sass (even though that's what you're using to write the HTML and CSS). Consider posting just the compiled HTML and CSS, and using those tags in your question instead. That will help you get many more responses, and help this question be relevant to more users in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have eventually grouped each text and slot for the solution.

Pug:

```
#lucky-draw
.title
  //- Pug loader currently does not handle webpack alias so we will use relative path here
  include ../assets/images/title.svg

.slots-container
  .slot-group
    .slot-text
      p Song Title

    .slot
      .slot__outer
        .slot__inner
          .slot__shadow
            #reel.reel

      #sunburst.sunburst
        img(src="~@images/sunburst.svg" alt="sunburst")

  .slot-group
    .slot-text
      p Genre

    .slot
      .slot__outer
        .slot__inner
          .slot__shadow
            #reel.reel

      #sunburst.sunburst
        img(src="~@images/sunburst.svg" alt="sunburst")
        
  .slot-group
    .slot-text
      p Style

    .slot
      .slot__outer
        .slot__inner
          .slot__shadow
            #reel.reel

      #sunburst.sunburst
        img(src="~@images/sunburst.svg" alt="sunburst")

button#draw-button.solid-button Run!
```

Sass:

```
.slot-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;

  .slot-text{
    font-size: 30px;
  }

  .slot-text,
    .slot {
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 10px; // Adjust spacing between text and slot
    }

  .slot {
    margin-right: 10px; // Adjust spacing between slots as needed
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you'll be outputting the results of a user action onto the page (e.g. displaying names when the user presses a button). Consider using the [`<output>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) instead of divs. It's more semantic, more accessible, and importantly: [labelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Content_categories#form_labelable:%7E:text=Elements%20that%20can%20be%20associated%20with%20%3Clabel%3E%20elements.) — which means you can use a [`<label>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) to give it a caption.

Consider changing your HTML structure to something more like this, and use CSS flexbox to ensure the labels stay centered above each output.

Also be careful not to duplicate the same ID multiple times within the same document, as that is invalid HTML. IDs can be used only once.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.slots {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.slot {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.slots output {
  width: 20ch;
  height: 2rem;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="slots">
  <label class="slot">
    <span>Left</span>
    <output id="slot-left" for="run-button"></output>
  </label>
  <label class="slot">
    <span>Center</span>
    <output id="slot-center" for="run-button"></output>
  </label>
  <label class="slot">
    <span>Right</span>
    <output id="slot-right" for="run-button"></output>
  </label>
</div>
<button type="button" id="run-button">Run!</button>
```